# How do I hide an Element-Label on a card in Dart/Polymer?

Tags: css, dart, polymer

I have a card and on top of it there is a Element-Label which adds a label or blank space if there is no label and I don't want that to show. I've tried to put this in the css....

```
.element-label
{
visibility: hidden;
display: none;
}
```

Here is a screenshot of the element, etc: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7Hf9K5d9C3TdkREOTg3YWFYVG8/edit?usp=sharing

I also tried:

```
querySelector('.element-label').style.display = 'none';
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I feel like I'm missing something stupid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the `/deep/` combinator to make the selector cross shadowDOM boundaries.

```css
* /deep/ #mainHeaderPanel /deep/ .element-label,
* #mainHeaderPanel .element-label /* for browsers without native shadowDOM support */
{
  visibility: hidden;
  display: none;
}
```